# How to combine index, and column name to form a new dataframe of single row record?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
AGR CON EXT NEU OPN
mean    0.488863    0.410159    0.551465    0.52    0.771065
std 0.080431    0.083976    0.082297    0.014142    0.040477
median  0.484974    0.394998    0.572734    0.52    0.768921
mode    ([0.38569774607708734], [1])    ([0.28385322332498814], [1])    ([0.4238607230643235], [1]) ([0.52], [2])   ([0.7036405063856129], [1])
min 0.385698    0.283853    0.423861    0.5 0.703641
max 0.620216    0.523491    0.633235    0.54    0.824629
```

the data frame has:
index= [mean, std, median, mode, min, max]
columns=[AGR, CON, EXT, NEU, OPN]

how do i transform this dataframe to get a new dataframe as below:

```
AGR_mean  AGR_std  AGR_median  ... ... ... OPN_min OPN_max
0.488863  0.080431 0.484974                0.703641 0.824629

Shape of df: 1x30
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.unstack()`:

```
# Create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100, 5)), 
                  columns="AGR CON EXT NEU OPN".split())
df = df.agg(["mean", "std", "median", "min", "max"])

new_df = df.unstack()
new_df.index = ["_".join(i) for i in new_df.index]
new_df = new_df.to_frame().T
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   AGR_mean   AGR_std  AGR_median   AGR_min   AGR_max  CON_mean   CON_std  \
0  0.521141  0.269817    0.514059  0.006849  0.997049  0.440883  0.262444   

   CON_median   CON_min   CON_max  ...  NEU_mean  NEU_std  NEU_median  \
0    0.422316  0.006271  0.979318  ...  0.462118   0.2822    0.462067   

    NEU_min  NEU_max  OPN_mean   OPN_std  OPN_median  OPN_min   OPN_max  
0  0.004241  0.97098  0.533487  0.294489    0.567492  0.02448  0.997053
```

Comment: @sammywemmy I didn't :) I realized that it's similar to `df.describe` so I made a dummy. But you can always use `pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep="\s+")` or `pd.read_clipboard`.

Comment: ahhhh ... yea, the other options you mentioned are familiar; thought you had a new super skill, becuase the shared data didnt look reproducible. cheers!

Comment: Normally, I would change the data a bit to fit into `read_csv` or use `engine="python"` with some regex like `\s{2,}` for `sep` to read, but in this case, data itself hold no meaning IMO, so I went anyway.